# How can I show divs that contains variables with multiple values?

Tags: jquery

I have a variable called **locName** which stores the name of a single location in my custom store locator. When I console.log **locName** after making my search, it returns the correct location names.

I want to show divs that contain these location names. My problem is that each location is stored in the same variable. They are not an array as far as I can tell so I cannot loop through each **locName** variable.

```
jQuery('#locations .loc:contains("'+ locName +'")').fadeIn();
```

The above code is only displaying one of the locations even though console.log lists all of the locations that need to be displayed.

In an if statement where a variable has a value, and there are multiple results, how do I loop through these?

Please see this jsfiddle here for a better example: http://jsfiddle.net/stormlux/drLnmfg6/

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) which reproduces the problem?

Comment: Need to see some additional markup...

Comment: Hello, I attached a fiddle in my above question. If you run it, the code will work, but thats because I faked how the distance is defined for each location. If scroll down in the jQuery you will see how I actually determine the distance and why it doesn't work. Thank you :)

Comment: The fiddle seems to do exactly what you say it doesn't.  I see the 4, skipping Napels and Jacksonville.  Using Chrome

Comment: The fiddle works because I faked the distance. If you scroll down under javascript you will see the actual code. Once I test the distance against the radius, it will console.log the correct names but not fadeIn all the results.

Comment: If you need to see the live example it is here: http://stormlux.com/uwr/contact/find-location/      search for the zip 32792 and set the radius to 100 miles. It will only display one location even though the console.log shows all the correct location names. All the html and javascript for the code is directly on the page.

Comment: Thanks everyone who helped. I used the code below to loop through each of the locations. I also found that I had a line of code that was causing each location to be hidden even if it was found. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to try another selector:

```
 jQuery('#locations .loc:[data-name="'+ locName.toLowerCase() +'"]').fadeIn()
```

and lowercase your data-name atrributes in html, also if you need overlapped search you could play with attribute selectors: `:[data-name^="name"]`.

If you do need an existing structure or more complex logic of locating `<div>` elements you could iterate through element set and put there your logic:

```
locName = (locName || "").toLowerCase();

jQuery('#locations .loc').each(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  var dataName = $el.text().toLowerCase();

  if(dataName.indexOf(locName)>=0) {
      $el.fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help in looping through each of the elements. I found I had another problem in my code that I was hiding the elements even if they were found. It works now. :)